# Use package com.android.phone.PhoneApp in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to override a method in the package **com.android.phone.PhoneApp**.
I have configured my eclipse to use internal classes using "http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/". How should I approach this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those instructions that you linked to are completely useless in your case.

You will need to download the complete Android Open Source Project (AOSP, http://source.android.com) and follow the instructions on that site for building a complete firmware image. You will then need to purchase a device for which the AOSP has complete drivers, or find other ways of getting the necessary drivers for your device. Then, you will need to install that firmware on your device. The XDA group may have some instructions on this "firmware modding" process that will assist you, though I do not have any links handy.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response...Seems like a very involved process.